# Excel text to convert date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a batch of data with several columns which the date is formatted like this:

May-31-2014.

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert that into a useful date format 05/31/2014. Any ideas?

Comment: Here http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel which explains more about the test to date that might help you.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8

Comment: Is the month always 3 letters or the whole month - it's hard to tell with May as the example! - what would 1st June look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a good few steps to achieving this.  This is one way to do it using formulas and helper cells.  If you need to do this without helper cells (i.e. you do not want extra columns) then you should mention this and I could probably work up some VBA to do the task.

The first task is to split your date out into 3 parts: the year, the month, the day.  Once you have those three then it's simple to piece it back together.

This is of course assuming that your dates **always** follow the Rather Idiotic American Date Format© of MMM-dd-yyyy.

This was done using the Microsoft page [Split text among columns by using functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8) as an example.

1. Splitting out the month:
   This is achieved using the `search` function to find the first `-` and the splitting tool `Left` to cut it out.

   `=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1)`

   which returns `May` from your example.
2. Splitting out the day:
   Is similar but a much more complicated use of the `MID` function is required.  We need to find the first and second `-` then subtract the location of the first from the second to get the length of the text required this results is a rather long function:

   `=MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1,SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)-SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1)`

   the `SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)-SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1)` returns the length while the `SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1` is simply getting the first location.  the `MID` tool cuts them out and returns `23` from your example.
3. Splitting out the year:
   The last tool we need is the `RIGHT` tool.

   `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1))`

   This simply gets the length of the string and then searches through it twice and returns everything that is left (or right).

The problem is now that you still have the month in an unusable text format.  To make is usable we need to use the `DATEVALUE` tool to convert it.  This tool wont accept a month on its own, but will accept a `MMM YY` string.  What we can do is then parse our month text into a number after we concatenate a year onto it.

4. Getting the Month as a numerical value:
   For the sake of argument lets say we stored out first function in cell B1.
   `DATEVALUE(B1 &" 01")` will return the date value string that excel uses internally, we can then wrap that in a `MONTH` function to return the numerical value for the month:

   `MONTH(DATEVALUE(B1 &" 01"))`
5. We can then merge all these into one `DATE(year,month,day)` function and thus convert it into a real date that Excel can use.  The month is in cell B1, the day in cell C1, and the year in D1 following the Stupid American Date Format™:

   `DATE(D1, B1, C1)`

   will then return `23/05/2014` in the cell.
6. If you want to get really fancy you can go ahead and combine all of the above formulas down into one.

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)),MONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1, SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1)&"  1")),MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1,SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1)-SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach is to take a string like *May-31-2015* and convert it into *31-May-2015*.  This conversion will allow us to use the ***DATEVALUE()*** formula.

So with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2),"-","") & "-" & LEFT(A1,3) & "-" & RIGHT(A1,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been answered, and I appreciate all the inputs. I would like to add this other option just in case is helpful to anyone:

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A1,5,2),"-",LEFT(A1,3),"-",RIGHT(A1,4)))
```

This will convert the date from the May-31-2014 format to 5/31/2014 format. Notice that in my specific case the months were entered with only three letter (e.g. Jul)

Thanks!

Comment: I would use `DATE` function with similar inputs, but in a different order, year - month day is required `=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)),MID(A1,5,2))` - this will work in any region